# How to get an excel file from AWS S3 bucket into a MultipartFile in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been trying to extract an .xlsx file from a AWS bucket I created and store it as a multipartfile variable. I've tried many different approaches, but at best I get weird characters. I'm not finding much documentation on how to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some examples of code you've tried?

Comment: @AndrewRueckert It'd be too much to post haha. But the closest come was when I tried using getObject to get an S3Object. Then creating a BufferedInputStream from the objectContent. Then looping through and reading it into a byte[], which was then used to create the file, but that didn't come out right as it said the created file was corrupted. This also didn't save as a var, but created a local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// you may need to initialize this differently to get the correct authorization
final AmazonS3Client s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient(); 
final S3Object object = s3Client.getObject("myBucket", "fileToDownload.xlsx");

// with Java 7 NIO
final Path filePath = Paths.get("localFile.xlsx");
Files.copy(object.getObjectContent(), filePath);
final File localFile = filePath.toFile();

// or Apache Commons IO
final File localFile = new File("localFile.xlsx");
FileUtils.copyToFile(object.getObjectContent(), localFile);
```

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "MultipartFile" - that's usually in the context of a file that's been sent to your HTTP web service via a multipart POST or PUT. The file you're getting from S3 is *technically* part of the **response** to an HTTP GET request, but the Amazon Java Library abstracts this away for you, and just gives you the results as an `InputStream`.